# Can \GetFileInfo read \ProvidesLanguage?

Tags: babel, documentation, dtx

I am not sure but it seems to me that `\GetFileInfo` used for documentation of `.dtx` files ignores `\ProvidesLanguage` from the `babel` system. Why?

Comment: David's code seems to work; can you make an example that fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does:

```
> \filedate=macro:
->2012/08/20.
l.10 \show\filedate

? 
> \fileversion=macro:
->v3.3p.
l.11 \show\fileversion

? 
> \fileinfo=macro:
->English support from the babel system.
l.12 \show\fileinfo

?
```

generated from

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{doc}



\GetFileInfo{english.ldf}

\show\filedate
\show\fileversion
\show\fileinfo
\stop
```

Comment: Thank you. I found the reason. It was in `russianb.ldf` which had `\ProviesLanguage{russian}[...]`. With `\ProvidesLanguage{russianb}[...]` (note `b` at the end) `\GetFileInfo` works fine although I am not sure if other things in `babel` will not break.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov ah, strangely enough it wasn't the russian one I tested:-) Glad you got it working (you could query that with the maintainer of that file, to see if it should lose the b)